# How to check if a button is currently active in flutter?

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, mobile-development

How can I check if a button is currently active in flutter? Below is the image for the button I am trying to create:

[[image: Below is the image for the button I am trying to create:]]

Comment: You can find the full code for this example https://github.com/huextrat/TheGorgeousLogin

Answer (score 1):

Flutter add toggle button in v1.9.1, which consists with a group of buttons that a callback that return which one is selected

You may check of link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html

A small example

```
ToggleButtons(
  children: <Widget>[
    Icon(Icons.add),
    Icon(Icons.car),
    Icon(Icons.menu),
  ],
  onPressed: (int index) {
//returned the selected index user chose
  },
  isSelected: isSelected,// which is a List<bool> that to define the selected button
),
```